# Saving multiple api response in a single object in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, hash, backend, httpbackend

I have a scenario where I need to convert multiple API responses into one object. Is it possible how? Below is my code. How do I convert it into one single object?

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

def make_request(url)
  HTTParty.get(url, headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json' }).parsed_response
end

numberone_apis = make_request('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name},{state code}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key}')

numbertwo_apis= make_request('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name},{state code},{country code}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key}')


numberthree_apis = make_request('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key})


puts numberone_apis
puts numbertwo_apis
puts numberthree_apis

convert_object2one = how ?
```

---

Comment: My first thought - look at deep merge (or just merge). It will largely depend on the response structure and your expected result structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to missing information on how the single responses look I can only recommend to build a new object. This answer is not optimized and highly opinionated based on the small given information.

```rb
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

def make_request(url)
  HTTParty.get(url, headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json' }).parsed_response
end

whole_response = {}

whole_response['numberone_apis'] = make_request('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name},{state code}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key}')

whole_response['numbertwo_apis'] = make_request('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name},{state code},{country code}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key}')

whole_response['numberthree_apis'] = make_request('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key}')

puts whole_response 

#=> 
{
  'numberone_apis':
    { ... },
  'numbertwo_apis':
    { ... },
  'numberthree_apis':
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: this works but doomed to fail due to lack of checking response code etc

Comment: @gates ye sure... This answer is based on OPs question. There is also no care about the response status so why would I extend the scope of the question with additional information that OP is possibly already aware off and left it out because it has nothing to do with his issue.

Comment: What can we expect between line 20 when you say { --- } @DennyMueller?

Comment: @gates I didn't think of that, thanks for the reminder. How would you implement if you need to add checks when the response fails?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to make a class that represents what this object. To get this to work you need a good name. Perhaps something like

```
class WeatherReport
  def initialize(...
    get_data
    assemble
  end

  def get_data
    make_first_request
    ...
  end

  def make_first_request
    @first_response = make_request('api ...
  end

  ...

  def assemble
   # add the responses together
  end
end
```